# Convert compressed SWF to AVI (or MPEG etc) via FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, video-conversion, file-format, swf

`ffmpeg -i compressed.swf out.avi`

gives the error

`[swf @ 0x10180b000]Compressed SWF format not supported`

so I tried

`swfcombine -d compressed.swf -o decompressed.swf`

`ffmpeg -i decompressed.swf out.avi`

but I get the error

```
[swf @ 0x10180b000]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
decompressed.swf: could not find codec parameters
```

Either a fix to the above process or different working CL utils would be appreciated!